# Python; How to solve ConnectionRefusedError while using socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to send data from python script over TCP and receive the same in the logstash.

Code :

```
import socket
import json
import sys

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 5959

print ("#STARTED#")

try:
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  print ("socket created. sock: " + str(sock))
except socket.error as msg:
    print ("error")
    sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
    sys.exit(1)

try:
  sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
  print ("socket connected to HOST: "+HOST+" PORT: "+str(PORT))
  print ("socket connected. sock: " + str(sock))
except socket.error as msg:
    print ("error")
    sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
    sys.exit(2)

msg = {'@message': 'python test message', '@tags': ['python', 'test']}
print ("sending message: " + str(msg))

sock.sendall(json.dumps(msg))
sock.send('\n')
print ("end")
sock.close()
sys.exit(0)
```

### Error :

ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     18 try:
---> 19   sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
     20   print ("socket connected to HOST: "+HOST+" PORT: "+str(PORT))

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     22 except socket.error as msg:
     23     print ("error")
---> 24     sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
     25     sys.exit(2)
     26

TypeError: 'ConnectionRefusedError' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Are you sure that port is open when you are sending the sockets? Try getting a response first from that server to see if you are even allowed to communicate to it.

Comment: [solved] i just changed the port and it works

Comment: Post the solution and mark as correct then. I figured that it was a port issue.